# Color fill table cells while also removing cell edges

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is seemingly very simple, but for some reason, I can either remove cell edges from a table, or fill the table cells with color, but not both. I'm using v3.4.2.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

values = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
columns = ['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3']
colors = [['y','y','y'],['w','w','w'],['y','y','y']]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.patch.set_visible(False)
ax.axis('off')
ax.axis('tight')

table = ax.table(cellText=values,
                colLabels=columns,
                cellColours=colors,
                edges='open',
                loc='center')
                        
plt.show()
```

Using the above code, the table edges are successfully hidden, but the cell colors do not appear. If I comment out `edges='open'`, however, the cell colors appear, but of course the table edges remain present.
[image]
[image]

I need to remove the cell edges, AND add the cell fill.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a better way than this, but one option is to explicitly set the edge color of all the Artists contained by the table to `'none'`.

```
table = ax.table(cellText=values,
                colLabels=columns,
                cellColours=colors,
                loc='center')

for c in table.get_children():
    c.set_edgecolor('none')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I'm honestly curious if there's a better way. Hopefully there is, and you get another (better) answer. I'm actually not super familiar with tables.

Comment: The unreleased version has edgecolor, which could have been another direction, but there doesn't appear to be something analogous to this in the current version - https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/table_api.html